# Domain name remove association with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Hi had website which was deployed on AWS Amplify and domain name was from GoDaddy, but now I don't have access to that AWS Amplify. I am trying to deploy that website again with Amplify but when I am trying to associate domain name with respective Amplify App it is throwing error saying

> `One or more domains requested are already associated with another Amplify app: www.example.in, example.in`

Is there any way to reset domain name association to new amplify app

Comment: Yeah: remove it from the old one. If you do not have access to it you need to get access to it again or ask someone with access to remove it.

Comment: Is there any other option, without getting access to old Amplify App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the old amplify App to resolve this issue. You may delete the amplify App following the below steps:

1. Select AWS region
2. Navigate to the [amplify App](https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/amplify/home?) and click your App
3. Click on the *Delete app* option from the top-right **Actions** button
   [image: AWS apmplify sample appp]